# How to trigger Matlab with Jenkins

Tags: matlab, jenkins

I would like to create a Jenkins job which would trigger and open Matlab in my computer. As my machine runs Windows 10, I have to `Execute a batch command` at the Build section, and add a command which would trigger Matlab.

I am not exactly sure which is the command that I should put there. I know where Matlab is stored in my computer, but I am not sure how to use this. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to read this [blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/01/20/the-other-kind-of-continuous-integration/), that explains how to setup a Jenkins continuous integration job for MatLab.

In the `Execute a batch command`, you should call something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe -nodisplay -r "disp('Hello World!');exit"
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. I tried following this blog, though at the stage where I need to put the command as it is suggested, the build eventually fails. The command which I wrote was: "C:\Users\Zachos\Documents\MATLAB\Examples\matlab.exe -nodisplay -r "disp('Hello World!');exit", and the build failed once again. This is the directory where Matlab is initialised by default in my computer. Not sure what exactly should I change.

Comment: On Windows you'll almost certainly need to add the `-wait` option, otherwise the batch command that wraps the call to MATLAB will exit immediately with a success status, even if MATLAB ultimately did not. If you're using Jenkins for unit testing or automated builds, it would seem as if they passed even if they failed.

Comment: @ZedKay use the directory where MATLAB is installed, not the directory where it starts up.

Comment: @SamRoberts Thanks, I will give it a try.